# How can a user choose items from a view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I've 3 types of users:

1. Author
2. Reader
3. Site Admin

**What I've done so far?:**

I've created Content Type named `Book`. `Authors`create account on my site & login & then add the information about the books they authored. I've a View with page-display named `books` which lists all the books which can be seen even by Anonymous user.

**What do I need?**

1. `Reader` should be able to pick 'x' no. of books from the this view. The no. of books a `Reader` can pick depends on his level `Voracious Reader`, `Moderate Reader`, `Occasional Reader`.
2. After `Reader` choosing `Book(s)`, `Site Admin` will be see the list of books picked by all Readers.
3. He'll then ship  the book to their address (offline) & update the status as "Shipped".
4. of course Readers should be able to see the list of all the books they've chosen along with its status.

**How do I accomplish the rest?**

Answer (score 1):

Install the [field collection module](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection).

Create a new field_collection field on the user profile called "ordered books".

Edit your "ordered books" field collection and add 2 fields:

- 1 called book - this will be an entity reference to your books
  content type. You will need the [entity reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) for
  this.
- 1 called status. This can be a list with values of "ordered" and
  "sent".

Now when users edit their profile then can select which books they want.

You will need to disable the status field at this point to lock it to ordered. (Use hook_form_alter).

Then also using hook_form_alter in a custom module add some extra validation to the user profile form.

In your new validation function check what sort of user is submitting the form (Voracious, Moderate or Occasional) and how many books they have selected and raise any errors as appropriate.

When a user looks back at their profile they will see a list of books and their statuses.

You may want to look into creating a new node type called "orders" or something. This could have an entity reference to the user, and entity references to books. That way you could have a status for the order a a whole as well as the separate books, but this is just an idea - you may not need it.